# un-hiding tabbar ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I'm working with two table view controllers. When a button is pressed on a cell from table view a, table view b comes up on top of a.

In the code for tableview a I wrote that when the button that takes you to table b is pressed self.tabbarcontroller?.tabbar.hidden = true.

That worked for hiding the tabbar but when i put the code in the second table view self.tabbarcontroller?.tabbar.hidden = false the tabbar doesnt come back.

```
// present view controller
    let vieww = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewTable") as! viewsVC
    vieww.view.backgroundColor = .lightGrayColor()
    vieww.view.alpha = 0.9
    vieww.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext
    vieww.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true 
    self.presentViewController(vieww, animated: true, completion: nil)

    // hide tabbar
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the code

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = false
```

to the **ViewDidAppear** method, rather than the **viewDidLoad** method in the original tableViewController.

> The issue you are encountering is that the view is not loaded after you go back, but rather appears right away since it has already been loaded beforehand.

It should look like this:

```
   override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

      self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = false
}
```

This should fix the problem.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: thanks for the response, i tried that but it doesn't seem to be working either. I think it could be because the presentation is set to over current context. So may the view is already appeared ? Is there anyhting else i could try

Comment: Try dismissing the view on top by popping it. That should do the trick. @sauly

Comment: am i able to do that if i presented it without navigation controller ?